# Working on AppScale's Datastore using terminal

Tags: python, cassandra, datastore, appscale

Following this [step](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Viewing-Data-in-AppScale-%28remote_api%29#connect-to-the-remote-shell) I managed to connect to AppScale's Datastore with remote_api. But can't have access to my models.
I have a file named "models.py" in my app, **i wanna import it to uses my db classes.**

```
myapp> import models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
myapp > from models import MyClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named models
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure you set your path so that it can find the model.py file.
Append to the path:
sys.path.append(os.path.join("/PATH/TO/FILE"))